# Why is my promise not properly setting my state?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a React frontend that calls my Rails backend, and I'm trying to write a promise that executes on this. However, I don't understand what is wrong with the promise I've written. I can see that the backend is responding with OK, however I'm having trouble setting my component's state to the data I'm retrieving

```
const [things, setThings] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    fetchThings();
}, [])

function getThingsPromise(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const url = "/api/v1/things/index";
        fetch(url).then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            }
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
        }).then(response => resolve(response))
    })
}

function fetchThings() {
    getThingsPromise().then((response) => {
        setThings(response)
    })
    console.log(things)
}
```

Comment: The code inside `getThingsPromise ` works fine (I've tried it with a public api) - any errors on the console?

Comment: No errors -- the console.log on 27 just returns an empty array

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't the console.log be inside the `then` callback? I think you are trying to log things and it's not yet populated since the promise is async

Comment: The state is set properly, but you won't see it until the next render.

Comment: Move the console log outside of the fetch things function and you’ll see the log when the state is finally set and the component is rerendered  (setState is added to the javascript queue and will not be available within the next line of code)

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't have a problem setting the data, you just put you console.log in the wrong place.
Setting a state in react happens asynchronously. At the time you log your state, it hasn't been updated with the received data yet. It will be available the next time the component rerenders, but then your fetchThings() function isn't being executed, so you don't see a log.
You can observe this if you place a console.log in the component body instead:
 At first render it will log the still empty state, then after receiving data the state gets updated, which causes the component to rerender. In this second render, the data will be available.

```
function App() {
  const [things, setThings] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchThings();
  }, []);

  function getThingsPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const url = "/api/v1/things/index";
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
          }
          throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
        })
        .then(response => resolve(response));
    });
  }

  function fetchThings() {
    getThingsPromise().then(response => {
      setThings(response);
    });
    console.log("The state hasn't been updated yet:", things);
  }

  // this logs the state every time the component renders
  console.log("First it's empty, then we have data:", things);

  return <div>result: {JSON.stringify(things)}</div>;
}
```

You can that example working here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-setstate-log-hjle1?fontsize=14